# JS Canvas transform image

Tags: javascript, canvas

Hello i want draw image in poligon but the image must be transformated not cropped
i have this code

```
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(300,400);        //1...0
ctx.lineTo(355,420);        //0...1
ctx.lineTo(355,400+237);    //0...2
ctx.lineTo(300,400+237);    //2...0
ctx.closePath();
ctx.save();    
ctx.clip();
ctx.drawImage(bgImages[Tram], 300, 400);
ctx.restore();
ctx.stroke();
```

but this is cropped image not transformated in polygon...
Thanks...

Comment: Your `ctx.clip` is causing the clip of the subsequent image. What exactly do you mean by 'transformated'?

Comment: I want use the image like As texture of polygon